# Is there a way to pass variables from ActionResult Methods without using a view model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Let's say I have a setup like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(int someUnrelatedNumber)
{
 ...
    return View();
}

[Post]
public ActionResult Create(SomeModel model, int someUnrelatedNumber)
{
 ...
}
```

Is there a way to pass 'someUnrelatedNumber' between them without creating a view model that contains 'SomeModel' and 'someUnrelatedNumber'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the ViewBag (or possibly even TempData if I understand what you're trying to do), but I tend to lean towards strongly typed view models whenever possible.

http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications

On the model binder side it will typically handle the bindings correctly, but you may have to provide hints to get it binding both SomeModel and a separate someUnrelatedNumber. Something like the following in the view.

```
<input type="hidden" name="someUnrelatedNumber" value="123" />
<input type="text" name="model.SomeRelatedNumber" value="123" />
```

etc...

Comment: Your saying use the ViewBag and the bindings, right? so instead of value="123" it would be value="@ViewBag.someUnrelatedNumber"? I'm not positive but I don't think ViewBag's can go from a controller to view back to controller? I may be wrong but I think I have tested that before.

Comment: Yes, you would grab the value out of the viewbag and put it into a hidden field. Then when you submit that form, someUnrelatedNumber gets posted to the new action along with the rest of the variables.